# Why does Git need to be fast forward for VSTFS build?

Tags: git, azure-devops, fast-forward

I'm working on backing up some data in our dev VSTFS Git repository. When I run the build, of course the build directory gets wiped, synced with Git repo, data is downloaded from an outside source and then pushed back to Git.

However, everytime this happens, even if I do a Git pull before I push, it will say I'm behind and need to fast forward. So I do a Git pull -ff.

However, I'd like to learn more of why this happens. Is it because the directory gets wiped everytime?

Here is the build:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bQlVTjVjdoSWR6ZkhGOVNTd0U/view?usp=sharing

You can ignore the Powershell, that just retrieves data.

This is the batch file

```
ECHO ADD GIT TO PATH
PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
ECHO TEST PATH
set PATH
ECHO GIT STATUS
git status
ECHO GIT CHECKOUT MASTER
git checkout master
ECHO GIT PULL FASTFORWARD
git pull origin master -ff
ECHO GIT ADD ALL
git add -A
ECHO GIT COMMIT ALL
git commit -m "Backing up Octopus P01 and P02"
ECHO GIT PUSH
git push origin master
```

Without -ff

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://xxxxxx:8080/tfsdev/xxxxx/_git/Development.Services'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Another way I've found to resolve this is to select Clean = true in the Repository settings in the build. That includes clean and reset

```
Syncing repository: Development.Services (Git)
Running 'git clean -fdx' on D:\BuildAgents\_work\7\s.
Running 'git reset --hard HEAD' on D:\BuildAgents\_work\7\s.
HEAD is now at ****** Updated GitTest.bat
Starting fetch...
Checking out ****** to D:\BuildAgents\_work\7\s
Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository Development.Services at commit ******
```

Comment: Do you pull before or after the build? What's the exact sequence of events? Are you following, basically, this guide? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart

Comment: To make this clearer, this is in the web portal, not in Visual Studio.

Comment: The pull happens in the build.

Comment: And you're saying if you remove that `--ff` you're told you need to fast-forward? `--ff` is the default behavior, so it should not be necessary unless there's something in your config saying otherwise. Do a `git config -l` and look for anything related to `pull`.

Comment: Share you detail build log on the oneDrive.

Comment: There's nothing in the config about pull. I've included the error that happens when -ff isn't included.

Comment: Could you share detail build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, share detail log of Run Script GitTest.bat step.

Comment: Here is the log:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bQlVTjVjdobk1MaHplQkExVDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, there are changes not staged for commit that lead the issue. You can clean repository before build.

[image]